# Divide a spreadsheet in two or more spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

How to divide a google spreadsheet (with about 100 sheets) in two (or more) spreadsheets (of about 50 sheets each) in google-apps-script ?

Alas, due to a google bug (see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/H2ZakBguOgk/discussion), I can't copy the entire spreadsheet file and delete some sheets in each spreadsheets.

I can only copy sheets one by one on another spreadsheet, then delete the original sheet(s) if copy is a success.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is the menu option "File > Make a copy..." not working too? It seems (on the link you pasted) that only the download is not working for you.

Comment: Yes both methods are not working : "File > Make a copy..." and "File > Download as / Excel". Same thing if I try to select the file from drive.google.com /More/Download/selected item/excel. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that should do what you want, I didn't test it so maybe you'll have to tweak some details but the general idea is there...

**EDIT :** I tested and made the corrections to make it work... *sorry for the typos in first version*

```
function splitSS() {
var oldFileID = 'original ss Id'
var newFile = DocsList.getFileById(oldFileID).makeCopy()
var newFileID = newFile.getId()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFileID);
Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets())
var todel = parseInt((ss.getNumSheets())/2);
Logger.log(todel)
var tokeep = ss.getNumSheets()-todel
Logger.log(tokeep)
    for (pa=ss.getNumSheets()-1;pa>tokeep;--pa){ 
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[pa]);
      var delsheet = ss.deleteActiveSheet(); // delete sheets begining with the last one
      Utilities.sleep(400);
    }
var ssold = SpreadsheetApp.openById(oldFileID);
    for (pa=todel;pa>1;--pa){ 
      ssold.setActiveSheet(ssold.getSheets()[pa]);
      var delsheet = ssold.deleteActiveSheet(); // delete sheets begining with the last one
      Utilities.sleep(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Many thanks ! ;) I have just tried your suggestion on another spreadsheet that has no problem before testing on the one that has problem. Alas I keep getting ""We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 3)". Just a detail : I hope I am right as I have adapted your second line with : var oldfileID = ("0Ajz_.....3NjJ1R0JiOUE") //'your original ss ID' ? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Hi, There were some errors in the code... now you have a working version. (I used ss in the second loop instead of ssold and also in the first loop I forgot the -1

Comment: Hi Serge, Many thanks. ;) Alas at the moment I keep getting the same error. I'll try again tomorrow if you don't mind. And I let you know. Thanks again. PS: I also answered above to Henrique.

Comment: As you like... I tested here on a spreadsheet with 20 sheets and I got no errors... good luck for tomorrow :-)

Comment: Hi Serge, I have still the same error with line3.
But thanks to your script I was able to do the following on a test spreadsheet (that has no "download as excel" error).
function copySS2() {
var oldFileID = ("0Ajz...TlE") //'your original ss ID'
var newFile = DocsList.getFileById(oldFileID).makeCopy()
}
And my file is copied in full (unless error from my part, all text and images are there). ;)

Now I have just done the test with to test my spreadsheet (that has "download as excel" error). About 5 minutes after a new file is created. ;)

Comment: Now I have to check by hand if everything is also there ! ;))
Thanks again. I'll write to you tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Hello, no time today! ;( Will answer ASAP. ;)

Comment: Hello, For one spreadsheet I ended up doing a copy one sheet by one sheet and check if the content is the same ...by hand!   I also tried to adapt your code see below. Thanks

Comment: function sp() {
    var oldFileID = ("0A..c")    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(oldFileID);
    Logger.log(ss.getNumSheets())
    var todel = parseInt((ss.getNumSheets())/2);
    Logger.log(todel)
    var tokeep = ss.getNumSheets()-todel
    Logger.log(tokeep)
        for (pa=ss.getNumSheets()-1;pa>tokeep;--pa){ 
          ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[pa]);
          var delsheet = ss.deleteActiveSheet(); 
          Utilities.sleep(400);
        }
    }

Comment: For spreadsheets that I can copy by hand ("file>make a copy..."), this script delete half the sheets. ;) It worked but alas for me the spreadsheet is still too big (I assume) so I can't download it as an excel file ! ;( So please could you let me know how to divide not by 2 but my let's say 3 or more ? Thanks in advance ;)